# Magento 1.9.0. getimagesize(): Read error!

Tags: magento-1.9, error, image

Does anybody know:

> 2019-02-21T19:45:40+00:00 ERR (3): Notice: getimagesize(): Read error!
>   in /pub/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product/Image.php on line 221
>   2019-02-21T19:45:40+00:00 ERR (3): Notice: getimagesize(): Read error!
>   in /pub/lib/Varien/Image/Adapter/Abstract.php on line 87
>   2019-02-21T19:45:40+00:00 ERR (3): Notice: getimagesize(): Read error!
>   in /pub/lib/Varien/Image/Adapter/Gd2.php on line 91

and

> 2019-02-21T19:39:01+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: imagecreatetruecolor()
>   expects parameter 1 to be long, string given  in
>   /pub/lib/Varien/Image/Adapter/Gd2.php on line 402
>   2019-02-21T19:39:01+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: imagecolorallocate()
>   expects parameter 1 to be resource, null given  in
>   /pub/lib/Varien/Image/Adapter/Gd2.php on line 289
>   2019-02-21T19:39:01+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: imagefill() expects
>   parameter 1 to be resource, null given  in
>   /pub/lib/Varien/Image/Adapter/Gd2.php on line 290

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Please add details.
Where do you have error ? Is your theme custom or native ? Do you have custom code linked to image ? If yes post it.

Comment: This is likely caused by having an image of size zero saved somewhere, but I can't point you to exactly where without more context. Probably somewhere in the media directory. What are you doing when this error happens?

Comment: The error is visible in system.log. The theme is custom. It is the ultimo theme from Infortis. My website is www.belladonna.de. I do not have any further code than the one from the theme.

Comment: I checked the media directory, it is all on 777.

Comment: @smstl Thank you!! This was the issue for me. Our drive had filled up a while back, leading to the creation of a couple of 0-sized files in /media/iwd_video/img/. Deleting them solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I got same error in my Magento 1.9.3.0 website yesterday and I have solved it!
Product image information assigned in admin But Product Image not in uploaded
 media/catalog/product/.. directories.
Please upload image and check it!
Mean Product Image not uploaded in Direcotries.
Also check permission of image if already uploaded in folder.
Thanks!

Comment: The image  is visible in the shop and can be uploaded. Anyway, I get this error. The permissions are on 777.